# "An Incompatible SQL Server version was detected" on VS 2013

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

I am using now VS 2013 along with SQL Server 2017, I keep getting this message every time I want to add a new SQL server database to my project.

Although I have installed and updating the SSDT for my VS 2013.
Does anyone is facing such message, or have a solution for that.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You'll need to download the latest bits to support SQL 2017. They'll include either the VS2015 or VS2017 IDE to work with them and you should be able to migrate in your existing projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSDT v16.x (version for VS2013) support SQL Server 2014, SQL Server 2012, SQL Server 2008, and 2008 R2

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/previous-releases-of-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt-and-ssdt-bi?view=sql-server-2017